# compare times with milliseconds

Tags: ruby, time

I have two dates a start date and an end date. I want to get a new time object which is the difference between the two. The differences I am concerned with are Hours, Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds. I need to be able to create a new Time object from the result that includes the milliseconds difference

```
>> require 'time'
=> true
>> start_time = Time.parse '1970-01-01T00:00:00.200'
=> 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
>> end_time = Time.parse '1970-01-01T01:01:01.400'
=> 1970-01-01 01:01:01 +0000
>> difference = Time.at(end_time - start_time)
=> 1970-01-01 01:01:01 +0000
```

my problem is that difference does not have the milliseconds

I can see that the Time has milliseconds by running

```
>> difference.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%L')
=> "01:01:01.199"
```

but how do I access the milliseconds that are in the Time difference object.

it is critical I have milliseconds as I am working in sub-second calculations?

## UPDATE

I don't think my first attempt at this question was as descriptive as it should of been, my apologies for that.

Comment: 1) `start_date = 1970-01-01 00:00:01 +0000` is not valid Ruby. 2) `1970-01-01 00:00:01 +0000` does not have any milliseconds either.

Comment: no it was an example I'll update with actual code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my problem is that difference does not have the milliseconds

It *does* have the milliseconds, `Time#to_s` / `Time#inspect` just doesn't show it. Its output is equivalent to: `strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"`

> how do I access the milliseconds that are in the Time difference object.

[`usec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html#method-i-usec) returns the microseconds and [`nsec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html#method-i-nsec) returns the nanoseconds:

```
time = Time.at(0.2)
time.usec #=> 200000
time.nsec #=> 200000000
```

For milliseconds you could use

```
time.usec / 1000 #=> 200
```

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'time'
a = Time.now
sleep(0.5)
b = Time.now
b - a
# => 0.505087
```

Milliseconds!

EDIT: Microseconds!

Comment: You don't have to require `time`.

Comment: Try [`Time#nsec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html#method-i-nsec). Nanoseconds!

Comment: @cremno: True. But basic `Time` is a bit sucky, I always require it if I do anything with times.

Comment: @Mauris: Yeah, but then I'd need `b.nsec - a.nsec`, I suppose. Microsecond precision is right there in the time difference.

Comment: `Time` is not limited to microseconds, it's your system clock

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's `Time` class has nanosecond precision: you can use [`Time#to_f`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html#method-i-to_f) to get a fractional number of seconds since the Unix epoch. If you subtract two `Time` objects, you'll get a fractional number of seconds between them. Thus, to get the number of milliseconds between two times, try:

```
((time2 - time1) * 1000).to_i
```